# Can't run AppCenter

Tags: appcenter, odin

I have AppCenter installed since I installed my OS6 Odin, today I installed Thunderbird via AppCenter, and now I want to uninstall Thunderbird but... I can't run AppCenter.
I tried reinstalling, purge, adding `repo bionic main` and `repo xenial main` to `appcenter.list` (it didn't exist, now exists). I think I tried everything found in the internet. I even tried to run AppCenter using terminal to see logs, but I didn't even see the logs, because of a long time of loading, then just stopped a process. Someone have any solution?

Comment: Based on the issue that you’re reporting, there may be a few things that need attention. What error do you see when you try to run AppCentre? Could you [edit] your question to include the Terminal output of these two commands: (1) `df -h` (2) `sudo ls /var/log`. These commands will show information about disk space and the size of your log files. With this information, it may be possible to offer a solution 

Comment: @matigo ught, that's a bit weird, but today I just started my PC and now it works, yesterday I tried restarting several times, didn't work then

Comment: There may have been a lock file in place that was preventing further updates. Glad the issue is resolved now 